# Installing libtcod for python returns “Access denied” im Terminal

Tags: python, cmd, terminal, access-denied, libtcod

I’ve been trying to follow the python3+libtcod roguelike Tutorial online but I’m stuck on the first hurdle.

As soon as I try to import “libtcodpy” to python I get a “Access denied” from my terminal.

I tried running in administrator already and access was denied, I also restarted the computer, and I checked the security and it claims that all users on the computer have full access to python and to the file where I unzipped libtcod.

Anyone know how to solve this issue? And is this likely to be an issue in the future or is it just with libtcod?

What can I do in future to avoid getting an “access denied” when installing other libraries for python?

I’m using windows 10 with the latest versions of python and the latest version of libtcod.

Answer (score 0):

Try running CMD or Powershell (terminal) as admin. 
That should allow you to install packages to the system.

To avoid this mess, I'd recommend setting up a virtual environment such as Anaconda or Virtualenv and using those to "host" your projects.

More about anaconda [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried already trying cmd as admin and navigated to the folder I unzipped the libtcod 1.7.0 folder too and put in this line: c:\> python -c “import libtcodpy” and it still gives me an access denied.  In the power shell I don’t get access denied but rather that it doesn’t know what c:\> is. If I navigate into the folder and then try to write the same code of “python -c “import libtcodpy” (without the c:\>) part I don’t get an error but it doesn’t seem to install correctly. Know what the reason for this could be. Also thanks for your virtual environment recommendation.

Comment: I solved it by using the python tdl and installing the c++ redistributable, however thanks for the virtual environment tip I will be using it in future